# how to send simple message on telegram with php?

Tags: php, telegram

In last few days I tried to connect my php app to telegram
I have my users phone number and I want simple code to do the job of sending them notification message and thats it nothing more

I checked official telegram documentation but still no clue how to get the job done

please ansewr as simple as possible

Comment: Useful Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82k6r4TMsIM

Comment: Your question is too broad. What do you want to use? Bot? telegram-cli?

Comment: If this is relevant, I will put it in the Answer section.

Comment: the point is i have no clue which one do what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

> **please answer as simple as possible**

. . .

> I checked official telegram documentation but still no clue how to get
> the job done

The Telegram documentation will only (barely) guide you on how to ***write a software library*** that can interact with Telegram Servers

> I tried to connect my php app to telegram
>
> I have my users phone number and I want simple code to do the job of sending them notification message and that's it nothing more

What you need a *ready-to-use* **PHP Telegram library** that handles all the interaction with Telegram Servers for you.

You can then use your PHP code to send messages to your users ***via*** that Telegram Library

You can [search GitHub for an actively developed PHP Telegram repo](https://github.com/search?l=PHP&o=desc&q=telegram&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)